# Группировка вёрстки по папкам (Android)

Tags: android

При росте проекта в папке layouts накопилось большое количество файлов с разметкой. Это естественно вызывает определённые неудобства.

Можно ли их каким-то образом корректно сгруппировать по подпапкам?

Comment: Хороший вопрос). У вас их сколько?

Comment: Счёт идёт уже на десятки.